# Is determining which niqabi is your wife a problem for Muslim men?

Tags: practical-islam, men, clothing, wife

One practical problem I see about women wearing niqab is that it may be difficult to distinguish one woman from another.  (E.g. "the one with long brown hair..." is not effective.)

[image: Niqabis; lower quality version of image sourced from http://www.wnyc.org/story/a-tweet-on-womens-veils-followed-by-raging-debate-in-saudi-arabia/]

**Question**: Is determining which niqabi is your wife a problem for Muslim men?

I'm curious about the situation of a Muslim man trying to find his wife among a group of women.  If a mistake were made, it could lead to all sorts of drama.  I'm wondering how big a problem this is, and if it is a problem, how it's resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might seem like a big deal from afar but from personal experience it is rarely an issue.

Consider the following distinguishing features:

- height
- build
- purses or other paraphernalia
- patterns/markings on their dress
- footwear
- accompanying children

And in the event of mistaken identity, the lady will make it clear by moving away or through lack of engagement. That is enough of a trigger for the men to know that something's amiss.